# Sizing a positioned element based on one child only

Tags: html, css

I have an absolutely-positioned container with two children.  I would like the width of the container to be based on the width of the first child, while the second child dynamically adapts to the width of its parent.

```js
const passenger = document.getElementById("passenger");
function toggle(){
  passenger.classList.toggle("squashed");
}
```

```css
#top {
  padding: 4px;
  border: thin solid red;
  position: absolute;
}

ul {
  padding: 4px;
  border: thin solid green;
}

li {
  padding: 4px;
  border: thin solid purple;
}

ul#passenger li {
  width: auto; /* ??? No good -- what goes here ??? */
}

.squashed {
  max-width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle()">Toggle</button>
<hr/>
<div id="top">
  <ul id="driver">
    <li>This is the desired width</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="passenger">
    <li>This should be forced to wrap because its width doesn't contribute to the container width calculation.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Click the "Toggle" button in the example to see an approximation of the effect I'm going for.  When I don't artificially constrain the width of `passenger`, it grows horizontally to fill the page, which pushes the width of `top` to match it.

I have tried setting `#passenger li {width:auto;}` as well as `width:100%;`, and also various combinations of `word-wrap`, etc, but I can't figure out how to force the `li` to take on the width of its parent.  It seems that `#passenger li {width:100%;}` only works when the width of `top` is explicitly set, rather than based on the width of `driver`.  It also "works" the way I want if I take `passenger` completely out of the flow by making it `position: absolute` but I want `top` to completely contain both elements, so this is not an option.

Is the desired effect possible using CSS only (no JS)?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `display: table` on parent element and some small width, for example `1%`, and then you also set `white-space: nowrap` on first `ul` element.

In this case all of the other child elements will adjust its width to the largest one.

```css
#top {
  padding: 4px;
  border: thin solid red;
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
  width: 1%;
}
#driver {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
ul {
  padding: 4px;
  border: thin solid green;
}
li {
  padding: 4px;
  border: thin solid purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">
  <ul id="driver">
    <li>This is the desired width</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="passenger">
    <li>This should be forced to wrap because its width doesn't contribute to the container width calculation.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Using `display: table` has some strange effects.  Try adding `right: 8px` to `top` and you'll see what I mean -- the border suggests the width of the table is based on `driver` but for positioning purposes the width is actually the stated 1%.

Comment: Yea, I can see the problem on Chrome (not sure if its a bug or that is how it should be) but it works fine on Firefox. Maybe you could use transform on chrome but not on Firefox like this https://jsfiddle.net/nahkqg4u/13/